# How to preserve the Attributes order in a XML after parsing and modifications in java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, tibco, stax

First of all, some premise.

I am aware of the existence of several identical questions on the site but in none of these I have found a definitive solution to the problem.
I know that the order of the attributes of xml files is absolutely irrelevant for the purposes of data consistency or the ability to integrate with software that actually treat xml as such and not as strings. However, I have to keep it because I am going to modify files that will be visually checked by the operators with WinMerge or with Tortoise’s check for modifications command.
I have used libraries like DOM, STAX and JDOM with poor results.
In the files where I only have to modify the text of an element, I have no problem and if there is some different formatting I can easily modify it considering it as a string.

With attributes it is more complicated. These are sorted in an other order(please do not question whether this is correct or not is not inherent to the question) and on winmerge looks like if all the document is was modified.

[image: the code is unreadable on purpose]

here is a (cutted and with semirandom textcontent) example of my xml first and after the modification

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <sca:composite xmi:version="2.0" 
      xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:BW="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/amf/models/sca/implementationtype/BW" xmlns:XMLSchema="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:compositeext="http://schemas.tibco.com/amx/3.0/compositeext" 
      xmlns:productAvailabilityResp="http://www.example.org/ERTETERET" 
      xmlns:property="http://ns.tibco.com/bw/property" 
      xmlns:rest="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/bERTERTETE" 
      xmlns:sca="http://www.3453434FDSSDFSD.org/xmlns/sca/1.0" 
      xmlns:scact="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/23E23E2E23Ee" 
      xmlns:scaext="http://2D2333DD32s" 
      xmi:id="_uKDz4IaiEeipW88nT3HxEA" 
      targetNamespace="http://tns.tibco.com/D23D32DD2232D2D2" 
      name="Q1231W1y" compositeext:version="1.0.0" 
      compositeext:description="TO EDIT VALUE" 
      ompositeext:formatVersion="2">
    </sca:composite>
```

and

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<sca:composite xmlns:sca="http://www.SDFSDF.org/xmlns/sca/1.0" 
    xmlns:BW="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/amf/models/sca/SDFS/BW" 
    xmlns:XMLSchema="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:compositeext="http://schemas.tibco.com/amx/3.0/compositeext" 
    xmlns:productAvailabilityResp="http://www.example.org/SDFSDFSD"
     xmlns:property="http://ns.tibco.com/bw/property" 
     xmlns:rest="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/SDFSF" 
     xmlns:scact="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/amf/models/sca/SDFSD" 
     xmlns:scaext="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/amf/models/sca/extensions" 
     xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     compositeext:description="test EDITED VALUE" 
     compositeext:formatVersion="2" 
     compositeext:version="1.0.0" 
     name="ERFERFRFE" 
     targetNamespace="http://tns.tibco.com/bw/composite/ERFERFREy"
     xmi:id="_uKDz4IaiEeipW88nT3HxEA" 
     xmi:version="2.0">
</sca:composite>
```

Could we try together to find a solution?

Edit like suggested from Federico:

What I need to do is to change the value from a single Attribute and the textcontent from an element, I can do do both of those things. But when I write back the file I find a different order of the attributes and a different formatting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sca:composite //same attributes
  compositeext:description="TO EDIT VALUE" 
  //same other attributes>

other stuff 

</sca:composite>
```

ps: my intent is making a versioner for tibco BW6 projects outside the designer

Comment: I'm surprised that stax changes the order of elements.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It would help if you specified (as in, in a detailed way) the kind of transformation you actually want to do, otherwise we may just throw guesses at what the correct solution could be.

Comment: hi @FedericoklezCulloca I'm editing my question thanks!

Comment: @DavideNotar good. Given your edit I think the last part of tquadrat's answer below may be the correct one. That is, if you can be sure that a simple search and replace won't cause damage (i.e. if it's a simple matter of *text* and not of *structure*, that is, the changes don't depend on the context of the element and you don't have content that correspond to your search string) go for it.

Comment: There are very few parsers or other tools that I am aware of that *guarantee* to maintain the order of attributes. However, many parsers do maintain the order in practice. So you may just need to be pragmatic and search around until you find a parser that behaves the way you want.  Ideally though, you should change the requirement. Your justification is "files that will be visually checked by the operators with WinMerge or with Tortoise’s check for modifications command": and therein lies the problem: you are comparing XML files with tools that do not do the job properly.

Comment: Hi @MichaelKay you surely have a legit point. In fact the code is working properly. I can version my Projects with no problem of any sort. But in fact this is a tool that must be used many times in a day on many projects, so consistency with the previous code is a priority. I hope you understand my point. I'm sure there is a way because Tibco BW6 himself does it in designer (even if those changes does not propagate in every part of the code like I want).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, your program reads the XML input stream from a file with STaX, DOM or SAX, then you do some modifications to elements or attributes, and finally your program will write the data to another XML file.

A requirement is that the detailed structured of the output file resembles that of the input file as close as possible, after the changes made. That means – among other conditions – that elements and attributes have to be in the same order in the output document as they were in the input document.

XML demands that the sequence of elements remains as is, but (as you said already), the attributes can be in any order without any influence on the semantics of the XML document.

Your problem is, that neither DOM or SAX nor STaX allow you to influence the sequence of the attributes for the elements.

Does this description match with *your* problem?

---

I am using a large XML file as "poor man's database"; that means that I manipulate that XML file with a text editor and that I have a bunch of little programs that create reports from that XML file. One of these will sort the "records" in the XML file, and this requires to read it, manipulate the data and to write it afterwards.

I had the same (at least similar issue) as you:  some attributes are at arbitrary locations afterwards. When searching through the text file in the editor, this causes a lot of friction.

So instead of using SAX, DOM or STaX for the output, I wrote my own library, that defined a comparator for each element type that is used to sort the attributes of that element type.

Some implementations of the comparator used a list with attribute names that defined the order, and that allowed me to have the attributes ordered like this:

```
<element sortkey="…" id="…" subject="…" date="…" parent="…" …
```

If you treat the `xmi:…` things and the namespace definitions all as attributes, the code for such an "XMLWriter" is quite straightforward.

If the order of the attributes may differ for each individual element (even those with the same name), you have to modify that approach in a way that you have to store the attribute sequence with each element instance on reading.

---

But perhaps XML processing is not the right approach for you at all …

Maybe an approach like that of using `sed` or `awk` fits better to your needs.

This means basically that you search for a certain sequence in the text file (using a regular expression or by line and column number or a combination of both), replace what you find there and start over for the next change on another location.

---

Edit: I did not mean to integrate either `sed` or `awk` into the solution;  what I meant was to adopt only the basic approach of how these tools work, and to implement that in the program. Both tools are really powerful, but from what I understand, only a fraction of their features is needed, so that a full integration of one or the other into the program might be overkill – nevertheless, it is possible: A starting point for an integration of `awk` is [awk.sourceforge.net](http://jawk.sourceforge.net/). It can be integrated even through JSR-223 (Scripting).
For an integration of `sed`, a look to the [tools4j/unix4j project](https://github.com/tools4j/unix4j/tree/master/unix4j-core/unix4j-command/src/main/java/org/unix4j/unix/sed) on github could be helpful.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, I have to keep all in a java application. Can I integrate those 2 tools in a Java project?

Comment: There are Java implementations for `sed` and `awk` in Java, yes. But what I meant was to adopt only the basic approach as these tools work, and to implement that in your program. Both tools are really powerful, but from what I understand, you only need a fraction of their features, so that a full integration of one or the other into your program might be overkill – nevertheless, it is possible. I did an integration of `awk` as a DSL into a ATP a few years ago …

Comment: Hi again tquadrat, I thik I will continue to search for a more "classic" solution using "mainstream" libraries. But thanks for your advices! If I'll give up I will came back to ask your help for implement this kind of solution! :-) edit: you answered with the oracle's link while I was writing too and it has appeared now. Thanks!

Comment: Starting point for an `awk` integration: http://jawk.sourceforge.net/. The other link was dead, sorry.

Comment: Really thank you so much! I read it immediately and try to get my hands on it tonight or tomorrow. Come on, let's hope to offer a solution for other people who have had this problem too!